# ActiveX object gets created in IE11 but missing first character of name

Tags: javascript, activex, internet-explorer-11

I'm working on getting a test print to an Ithaca (USB) ticket printer to work via a test html page on our intranet.  The developer who created the dll gave me the source and the installer.  I've installed the dll for the printer and the ActiveX object gets created (IE11).  I've added the intranet site to Trusted Sites and I've configured the trusted sites 'custom' settings to radiobutton: Enable download of signed, download of unsigned, and initialize and script under the ActiveX section.

here's the script:

```
<script language="javascript">

    <!-- Load the ActiveX object  -->
    var x = new ActiveXObject("IthicaEpicPrinter.IthicaPrint");
    var status = x.getPrinterStatus();
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += status;
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += "ok";

    x=null;
  </script>`
```

What happens is the following:

-with the dev tools window open, after the object loads, if I expand the object to view the methods, the method names (on the right hand side of the dev tools window) are missing characters.  Most of them are missing the first character and some are missing trailing characters.  On my co-workers computer, running in IE9, he gets the full method names as they appear in the interface in the code.

Here's what the interface looks like:

```
namespace IthicaEpicPrinter
{
[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
[Guid("**********")]
public interface IIthicaEpicPrinter
{
     Boolean isIthicaEpicPrinter();
    Boolean shutdownPrinter();
     string printParkingComps(string printstream);
     string printComps(string printstream);
     string printTemplate78();
     string printCash(string printstream);
     string printTRVoucher(string printstream);
     string getPrinterStatus();
     string printstream(string streamLayout, string streamParameters);

}
}
```

Here's a screenshot of my dev tools window with the area in question highlighted on the right:

[link to pic](https://scontent-lax.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfa1/t31.0-8/11084138_10205061270225058_1891238673830416315_o.jpg)

Thoughts?

Comment: type
navigator.platform in the IE developer tool to determine the bitness of the page. and the ActiveX control.
does this match that of your co-worker's? I would guess that one of you is using the x86 or x64 version and that the control developer has give you different builds of the x86 and x64 versions. Rebuild the controls project.

Comment: just an update: Typing navigator.platform on both of our systems resulted in outputting Win32.  In doing some research on the issue, the behavior I'm seeing might be related to a couple of MS security fixes installed on my computer.  The possible resolutions are long winded, so I'm not going to attempt them.  In the meantime, I've commented out the activex object creation in my code as I just need to get the code to continue past that action without stopping the application.

Comment: just wanted to chime in with an update.  I recently had to revisit this code and resolved the issue by recompiling the object in 64 bit.